# How to load data from property file into bean property values?

Tags: java, xml, spring, properties, javabeans

I am following the following article.

http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-quartz-scheduler-example/

Everything works fine.

```
<bean id="simpleTrigger"

    class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerBean">

    <property name="jobDetail" ref="runMeJob" />
    <property name="repeatInterval" value="5000" />
    <property name="startDelay" value="1000" />

</bean>
```

I created a property file app.properties which has

```
 repeatInterval = 5000
 startDelay = 1000
```

I want to load these data into bean properties. Right now I have to hard code the values into the xml file.

I want to be able to load the data from property file into the bean properties. Is it possible?

EDIT:

I have

`<property name="repeatInterval" value="5000" />`

What I am looking for is a way to make it

```
<property name="repeatInterval" value= "get 5000 from property file" />
```

Comment: Are you looking for something fancier than reading in the properties using Properties and calling the setters on your beans?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find a file `myPropertyFileName.properties` that is on your classpath and load it into your spring config, create the following bean:

```
<bean id="myPropertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="location" value="classpath:myPropertyFileName.properties"/>
  <property name="placeholderPrefix" value="${props:"/>
</bean>
```

Then use a property name defined like

```
repeatInterval=5000
```

like this:

```
<property name="repeatInterval" value="${props:repeatInterval}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Spring `propertyPlaceholderConfigurer` to achieve this. [Follow this guide](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-quartz-scheduler-example/).

Answer (score 0):

I have run into something similar in the past. I needed to load a bunch of beans using Spring but I wanted them to be user editable bean files. So I didn't want to include them in the jar packaging. What I did was create my user-defined bean files outside the jar but in a know relative location. My packaged bean definition file referenced the beans defined in the user-defined bean file and when I loaded the application context I provided both files (user-defined & packaged).

Bit unorthodox but it worked.